# Portion Margin of Error with Known N

Tags: confidence-interval, sample

Would it be possible and helpful to add a known population N to the function below?

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

def MOE(successes, n):
    p_success = successes/n
    se = np.sqrt(p_success * (1-p_success)/n)
    z_score = 1.96
    lcb = p_success - z_score * se #lower limit of the CI
    ucb = p_success + z_score * se #upper limit of the CI
    ci = sm.stats.proportion_confint(n * p_success, n)
    moe = p_success - ci[0]
    return ci[0], ci[1], moe

print(MOE(50, 120))
```

Result:

```
(0.32845820581928914, 0.5048751275140442, 0.08820846084737755)
```

I ask because the margin of error seems to be near 10%, but what if the population N is just 200?